# How to set color of a pen from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, pen

I thought this would be covered somewhere, but I can't find it.

In WPF how do you set the color of a System.Drawing.Pen from a string (like "Red")?

Again, this isn't a brush, this is a pen.

Comment: pass the result of Color.FromName() to the Pen() ctor?

Comment: No such beast as Color.FromName() for Pen. I think that only works for brushes.

Comment: i mean `x = new Pen(Color.FromName("Red"))`

Comment: Hey! That's it! Thanks!